# How do I make my code analyse the sentence then list the position on a text file

Tags: python

So far i've got this

```
UserSen = input("Enter a sentence of your choice, ")
position = {} # word -> position
words = UserSen.split()
for word in words:
    if word not in position: # new word
        position[word] = len(position) + 1 # store its position
```

I want to make it out put something like, if you put in the sentence "HI HOW ARE YOU HI ARE YOU HI" it would output 1,2,3,4,1,3,4,1

Comment: So why not study it now - search the web and find out what it means?

Comment: Don't post Python code without indentation.

Comment: You almost got it.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple, you need to save a list within the positions found so far:

```
# UserSen = "HI HOW ARE YOU HI ARE YOU HI"
UserSen = input("Enter a sentence of your choice, ")

# word -> positionDictionary
positionDictionary = {}
positionList       = []
words              = UserSen.split()

for word in words:

    # print( word )

    # new word
    if word not in positionDictionary:

        # store its positionDictionary
        positionDictionary[word] = len(positionDictionary) + 1

    positionList.append( positionDictionary[word] )

    # print( positionDictionary )
    # print( positionList )


print( positionList )
```